# nginx sets the wrong Content-Type header for dynamically generated files

Tags: nginx, content-type, mpdf, hhvm

I have a web application that dynamically generates PDFs using mPDF (v6.0.0, http://mpdf1.com). While everything works fine with Apache and PHP I have some troubles with nginx + HHVM.

The thing is that nginx refuses to set the correct Content-Type header which would be application/pdf. Instead it keeps settings text/html no matter what I do/change in the code or environment config with the result that the binary data of the document is displayed in the browser window. I am using the Output() method of mPDF without any parameter so the PDF is meant to be rendered inline: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125

Looking at the source code (Line 8295 of mpdf.php) everything should be just fine: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpdf/mpdf/v6.0.0/mpdf.php

I already ensured that "application/pdf" is in the mime.types file. Setting a location directive to all URIs ending with .pdf á la "add_header Content-Type application/pdf" did not work either.

Here is the cURL output, that led me the right direction:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 08:13:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1571243
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: HHVM/3.10.1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-disposition: inline; filename="mpdf.pdf"
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 08:13:29 GMT`

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

### Update:

It turned out that HHVM was the problem. There seems to be a bug when using the `header()` method multiple times on the same Header. After switching to PHP-FPM it was just fine. I also had to make sure that the `HOME` variable (in PHP's `$_SERVER` array) is in sync with the acutal directory of the web apps files.

Comment: *Setting a location directive to all URIs ending with .pdf* will not work, because the location is ultimately a php file.

Comment: Check what php sends. For dynamic pages nginx does not generate content type header

Comment: Thanks, guys. Thing is i can not influence the Content-Type header in the code even if i set it in the line right before the output happens, L. 8308: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpdf/mpdf/v6.0.0/mpdf.php

Comment: @AlexeyTen can you elaborate on that? Got the same problem /w a php file that generates xlsx. PHP sets the header correctly but once nginx is involved and default text/html is guessed. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @MattBannert create your own question with nginx's config, and example of request and responce